# Error al Usar threads Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto c#

Tags: c#

Buen día.
Tengo una pagina donde la persona ingresa sus datos,se guarda en la BD, y envia un correo y aparece un modal.
Todo bien al usar la funcion que enviar el email pero cuando lo pongo para que se lanze en un Thread, me sale el siguiente error.

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Funciona bien de esta manera.

```
EnviarCorreo(nombre, telefono, correo, dum);
```

De esta manera ya no funciona

```
Thread miHilo = new Thread(delegate()
{
  EnviarCorreo(nombre, telefono, correo, dum);
}); miHilo.Start();
```

> Funcion

```
   public static void EnviarCorreo(string nombre, string telefono, string correo, string dum)
    {

        try
        {

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress(data, data, Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.Subject = "data"

            //Aqui es DONDE ME SALE ERROR,PERO CUANDO LO LLAMO DE MANERA NORMAL , NO ME SALE ERROR, AL USAR THREAD, SI ME SALE ESE ERROR JUSTO AQUI
            LinkedResource imagenLogo = new LinkedResource(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Assets/imagenes/logo.png"), MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            imagenLogo.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

He estado buscando pero no entiendo bien la diferencia en este caso.
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas dentro del thread dejas de estar en el contexto web, por lo tanto `HttpContext.Current` no aplica, por eso seguramente este en null, deberias enviar el valor por parametro

```
string logo = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Assets/imagenes/logo.png");
Thread miHilo = new Thread(delegate()
{
   EnviarCorreo(nombre, telefono, correo, dum, logo);
}); 
miHilo.Start();
```

entonces el metodo recibe el valor

```
public static void EnviarCorreo(string nombre, string telefono, string correo, string dum, string logo)
{
   //codigo
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.
No sabia eso de Thread, gracias aprendí algo nuevo!